# U may be a victim of software counterfeiting

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-xp, windows-security

I installed a Windows XP VM on my system with genuine Windows 7. But when I start my VM, the windows XP shows a popup with message :
"u may be a victim of software counterfeiting"
Is this a concern ? I mean, can it cause a legal problem for me ?
I am not asking about the hacks to remove this message but about if it may lead to some legal issue ?
I also know that one should only use a genuine Window provided by microsoft directly. What I am doing is for study purpose only.
Thanks in aadvance !!!
Sorry if asked at wrong place/forum (confused where to ask) !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That message will come if the xp version you are running is likely to be a cracked version. It is, of course not legal to use cracked software, and yes, it could cause a legal problem for you, **as much as it could for anyone using a cracked version of windows.**

Depending on what you are doing for 'study purpose', there might be other solutions. But else, if you don't want to use counterfeit software, go buy XP.

Comment: Can one even purchase an xp license these days?

Comment: Very valid question. I have no idea. Its probably possible... But even if it wasn't, its still illegal and could cause legal problems to use a cracked version! :P

Comment: Thanks Jite !!!  I was just looking to play around with windows registry.Can you please suggest if there is some alternate solution..

Comment: You could always try contact Microsoft and ask to buy a XP disk. If you are in school, check if they have dreamspark, think dreamspark have free XP for students. And if you are only using it to try out webpages in diff OS's and browsers, MS provides disk images for (I think) XP on their site.

Comment: @SushilKumar Feel free to mark the answer as correct if you feel you got what you wanted! :)